# Generate directed lattice with equal number of neighbours for each node

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to generate a lattice with 100 nodes but would like to ensure that all nodes have the same number of neighbours.

However when I do:

```
d=graph.lattice(100,0,nei=10,directed=TRUE,circular=TRUE)
get.edgelist(d)
```

then I can see that many of the nodes do not have the same number of neighbours.

Is there any way to ensure that every node has the same number of connections assuming that the first column represents nodes and the second column connections?

Comment: How do you propose to deal with the fact that 2 of the nodes only have 1 neighbor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default edge directions for `graph.lattice` are not the best for directed graphs. What you can do is creating an undirected graph, and then converting it to directed:

```
d <- as.directed(graph.lattice(100, 0, nei=10, directed=FALSE, circular=TRUE))
unique(degree(d, mode="in"))
#  [1] 20 
unique(degree(d, mode="out"))
#  [1] 20
```

If you want non-mutual edges, then the easiest (but somewhat less readable) solutions is

```
d <- graph(sapply(1:100, function(i) {
  rbind(i, ((i+1):(i+10)-1) %% 100 + 1)
}))
unique(degree(d, mode="in"))
# [1] 10 
unique(degree(d, mode="out"))
# [1] 10
```

Comment: but why does it has a degree of 20 when each node has 10 neighbours?

Comment: Because there are mutual edges everywhere. But use the second solution if you don't want mutual edges.

Comment: Could this same method be applied to uneven number of neighbors? I would like a lattice graph where each node has exactly 3 neighbors. But when I plot such a graph I get 6 edges for each node. Is there a way to get the same graph with only 3 edges each?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a edgelist and make the graph from that. In that case, assuming that you only consider neighbors linked to (directed), then you could do something like:

```
el <- do.call(rbind,
              lapply(1:100,
                     function(e) {cbind(rep(e,10),
                                        sample(setdiff(1:100, e),10))}))
d <- graph.edgelist(el)
```

This picks 10 random nodes (other than itself) to link a node to.

Comment: It is a random graph. I misunderstood and thought that was what you wanted.